# how save a selected record into a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in a problem with the following query ..

After inserting in the table rtoxvta record by record, I need before the end of the loop eliminate the record of the vta table prevously selected.

For that i declare a new variable and assign it the vta id .. **but where do I do it?**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ROWPERROW;
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE PROCEDURE ROWPERROW()
BEGIN
DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE indexx INT DEFAULT 0;
#DECLARE aux INT DEFAULT 0;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rto INTO n;
SET n = n +1;
SET indexx=0;
WHILE indexx<n DO 

 INSERT INTO rtoxvta (fecharto, importerto, fechavta, importevta)
  SELECT r.fecha, r.importe, v.fecha, v.importe
    FROM vta v
    left outer join rto r 
    ON r.id = indexx
    WHERE v.fecha >= r.fecha
    AND (
    (v.importe = r.importe) OR 
    (v.importe + 2 = r.importe) OR  
    (v.importe + 1 = r.importe) OR 
    (v.importe - 1 = r.importe) OR 
    (v.importe - 2 = r.importe))
    LIMIT 1;

  SET indexx = indexx + 1;

  #DELETE FROM vta WHERE id = aux;

END WHILE;
End;
;;

CALL ROWPERROW();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do it as two steps. First get the ID of the record you're going to insert into a variable, then insert that record. Then you can delete the record.

```
WHILE indexx<n DO 

  SELECT v.id, r.id INTO @v_id, @r_id
    FROM vta v
    join rto r 
    ON r.id = indexx
    WHERE v.fecha >= r.fecha
    AND r.importe BETWEEN v.importe - 2 AND v.importe + 2
    LIMIT 1;

 INSERT INTO rtoxvta (fecharto, importerto, fechavta, importevta)
 SELECT r.fecha, r.importe, v.fecha, v.importe
 FROM vta v
 CROSS JOIN rto r
 WHERE v.id = @v_id AND r.id = @r_id;

  SET indexx = indexx + 1;

  DELETE FROM vta WHERE id = @v_id;

END WHILE;
```

Also, if you're using a column from `rto` in the `WHERE` clause, you should use `INNER JOIN` rather than `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. The `WHERE` condition will not match any rows that don't have a match in `rto`, so there's no point in using an outer join.

Comment: I don't understand what you do :-) - But do you really want `SELECT @v_id := v.id, @r_id := r.id` to return a result set for every loop iteration? You might want `SELECT  v.id,  r.id INTO @v_id, @r_id` instead.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel It has `LIMIT 1`, so there's only one iteration.

Comment: Each time through the `WHILE` loop it selects one row from the table, inserts it into the other table, then deletes that row from the original table.

Comment: Why would you write a loop for only one iteration?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The `WHILE` loop does multiple iterations, the `SELECT` just has 1 iteration.

Comment: The SP will generate one result set for every executed SELECT statement, if you don't use `INTO`. It doesn't matter that every result set will contain only one row.

Comment: I doubt he's actually using the result set, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: Doesn't matter for the functuanality - But why waste ressources? :-) ... I'd like to upvote this - But I can't since I don't get what's going on here. A range condition in WHERE with `LIMIT 1` without ORDER BY looks really strange.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The order doesn't matter. The loop runs as many times as there are rows in `vta`. Each iteration picks one row, inserts a row into the other table based on it, and then deletes that row. When it's done, every row will have been processed and deleted.